# Phonegap, Lawnchair and Cookie in Android

Tags: android, cookies, cordova, local-storage, lawnchair

I'm using Lawnchair with in my Android Phonegap App. For most of my users, Lawnchair works well. But for some reasons, some of my users say that the settings are not saved (i use Lawnchair with DOM Adapter to save settings). Are there any other adapters that i can use with phonegap for Android? I saw Cookie Adapter but it is for the previous version of Lawnchair

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many adapters in lawnchair to store stuff.
http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/adapters/

The way lawnchair works is, if an adapter is specified, it will use that, or if no adapter is specified and if the code of all adapters is appended to lawnchair.js file, then lawnchair checks which one to use in the order of they are appended and picks the first one it finds suitable. 
Moreover the dom adapter works fine for my android app. Update your code to the latest lawnchair on github. So i guess the problem could be somewhere else too, maybe the data u are storing. Check out.